# Force Umbraco to use https for back office and http for all other requests

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, umbraco

I am trying to configure Umbraco so all requests to the back office (www.mydomain.com/umbraco) get redirected to https and all non-backoffice requests are forwarded to http.

I can easily get the back office to use SSL by setting this web config appsetting key:

```
<add key="umbracoUseSSL" value="false" />
```

However, I am struggling to get all other pages to force http. The certificate is self signed so I don't want end users getting SSL errors. I have tried this rewrite rule in the web.config, but it has no impact.

```
<rule name="No-https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" negate="false" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="umbraco" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
</rule>
```

My aim is that any request to **https**://www.mydomain.com is redirected to **http**://www.mydomain.com unless it matches the folder /umbraco.

If I have this rule, all http requests are redirected to https:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">  
   <match url="(.*)" />  
   <conditions>  
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />  
   </conditions>  
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>
```

But when I negate the rule, it no longer has any effect?

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">  
   <match url="(.*)" />  
   <conditions>  
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" negate="true" />  
   </conditions>  
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />  
</rule>
```

---

Update. It looks like it isn't possible to process the redirect because the browser is giving the https error before the rewrite rule runs? [Redirect from https to http when the SSL cert is no longer valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521496/redirect-from-https-to-http-when-the-ssl-cert-is-no-longer-valid). Is there any way to redirect to http when using a self signed certificate?

Comment: It's not possible to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP before the user sees the certificate warning. This is explained in the SO link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try amending your rule to only match on the Umbraco path, something like this:

```
  <rule name="Force SSL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^umbraco/(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
  </rule>
```

That way http requests for anywhere other than the umbraco path will not be redirected. For https > http requests try the following (untested)

```
  <rule name="Force Http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="ON" />
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^umbraco/(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
  </rule>
```

Comment: Answer updated with potential solution for your second request

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into making `/umbraco/` unavailable on your site, and making it HTTP only.

I would then setup a different site, perhaps `umbraco.yoursite.domain` which does require SSL and allowing that address to access Umbraco.

Also, have you considered using [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to get a proper SSL certificate for your site?